# Can two 3×3 scrambled rubix cube be exact same?

Tags: algorithm, logic, mathematical-optimization, cubes, rubiks-cube

What do we mean by solved cube? Solved cube is one which have same color (centre dot color is considered as face color) on all 6 faces.
For solving for this problem there are lots of algorithms discovered.
But what if we want to make one scrambled cube exact same as another scrambled cube we have? Is it possible to do? If yes then how?

Comment: This question may be more suitable to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Trivially so.  If you play back the moves required to solve a cube in reverse order, reversing each one, you'll find a sequence that gets from a solved cube to the original scrambled one.  So solve the first, then unsolve it to get to the second.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/.